# PostgreSQL: Put the values in one column as header in result set?

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, crosstab

Let's say I have two tables, one with schools and one with classes. Both tables have SchoolID so they can be matched. They look something like this:

TableSchools

```
SchoolID SchoolName
1        SchoolOne
2        SchoolTwo
3        SchoolThree
```

TableClasses

```
ClassID SchoolID ClassName
1       1        ClassOne
2       1        ClassTwo
3       2        ClassThree
4       2        ClassFour
5       2        ClassFive
6       3        ClassSix
7       3        ClassSeven
```

and I want my resultset to be like this

```
SchoolOne   SchoolTwo   SchoolThree
ClassOne    ClassThree  ClassSix
ClassTwo    ClassFour   ClassSeven
NULL        ClassFive   NULL
```

I've heared in TSQL I could use `group by with rollup` but it seems that's not possible or at least I don't understand how to use it [from here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/queries-table-expressions.html).

Comment: You are not looking for `rollup` you are looking for a "crosstab" aka "pivot".

Comment: I've checked out the PostgreSQL documentation regarding crosstab and it seems to me like I have to name the column names/headers manually when using it. That doesn't really cut it for me as the amount and the names of the schools is flexible. Otherwise I could also simply use column aliases. Or am I missing something major?

Comment: The third column name in your desired result is `SchoolThree`. As there are no data like this in `TableSchools`, I'm thinking: is this a typo or the names should be sequential, even not matching the `SchoolName`s in `TableSchools`?

Comment: Things like that are **much** easier implemented in your application. You can't define column names dynamically based on the result in a SQL statement.

Comment: @FelyppOliveira it was a typo, fixed. Thanks for the heads up!

a_horse_with_no_name I guess that seals the deal, thanks tho.

Answer (score 1):

Not EXACTLY a pivot, but should allow the same programatic results in your code:

```
select ts.schoolName 
, array_agg(tc.className order by tc.className) vals
from tableSchools ts
join tableClasses tc tc.schoolID=ts.schoolID
group by ts,schoolName
```

Note: Depending on your client, it might be easier to return JSON instead of array.. let me know if you need help with that part and I'll update.